# How to add a delay between iterations of an infinitely repeating animation in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a `<div>` filled with `<span>` elements that fade in and out. After the last one appears, it stays around too long and collides with the first one in the second iteration. At no point should the text overlap/blend into each other. Making it 15s causes the text to bleed into each other turning the transition.

What can I change to make them all flow nicely?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 377px;
  margin: auto;
}

span {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 121px);
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 26.4px;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: fadeEffect 12s linear infinite 0s;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sentences">
    <span>the quick brown fox</span>
    <span>jumps over the lazy dog</span>
    <span>on the way to the market</span>
    <span>to get some food</span>
    <span>for his good friend</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle (with SCSS)](https://jsfiddle.net/rzgfquwk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to increase the animation length so it doesn't start at the beginning before the last one finishes

```
  animation: fadeEffect 15s linear infinite 0s;
```

Comment: Sorry should clarify, that at no point should the text overlap/blend into each other. Making it 15s causes the text to bleed into eachother turning the transition.

Comment: Ah I see. The problem is that you don't have a delay on the first span so it just starts immediately when it loops back. Do you need the first span to immediately be visible or could you just apply the animation to that one as well?

Comment: It would be preferable for it to be immediately visible.. is there a workaround?

Comment: How strict are you on the current fade animation? You could set it to 15s and tweak the animation a bit so they don't overlap ever

Comment: Tweak as dont use a fade?

Comment: No I mean if you do something like setting the animation length to 15s and then maybe set the 10% opacity to 0 then they won't overlap anymore.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!